# js files under node_modules not found when using Angularjs with node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, node-modules

My application is serving angularjs's index.html from node as below,

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.render('index');
})
```

When I open the application in browser, I see following errors on node console, The below files are not found,

```
GET /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 404 7.506 ms - 172
GET /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 404 8.439 ms - 178
GET /systemjs.config.js 304 9.265 ms - -
GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 404 12.038 ms - 179
GET /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 404 0.622 ms - 172
GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 404 0.589 ms - 179
```

I tried using CDN path as below,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

but then it is unable to load some other js files under node_modules. This all works fine when I use angular pages statically without express.
How do I refer to js files under node_modules so these are loaded correctly.

Comment: `GET /systemjs.config.js 304 9.265 ms - -` ???

Comment: would you please show your `systemjs.config.js ` file?

Comment: Hi Shimon, I checked systemjs.config.js after your response and modifed the below,                                                                                  
      // paths serve as alias
      //'npm:': 'node_modules/' to 'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com//'. There are no more 404 errors. Is this the correct way to refer nodu_modules js files in any node/angular application

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve them as static files : [documentation here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I am currently using it as  below,app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, ''))); gave blank because my index.html is under src i.e at the level of app.js.

Comment: basically you can serve mutliple folder but you have to alias them like this :

`app.use('/static', express.static('public'))` ('/static' will be the path to put in index.html)